# How to change the value of all nodes in a BST tree?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

How can I change the value of all the nodes in a tree ?

I filled my BST tree with multiple key-value.

Everything is working perfectly, I just didn't know how can I change the value of all of the node by adding log2 on them.

How can I iterate through each node ?

my Node.hpp

```
class Node{

    private:
        Node *left;                     //left child
        Node *right;                    //right child
        std::string num;
    public:
        int data;                       //number
        Node();                         //constructor
        void setData(string num, int data);         //sets number in node
        string getData();                   //return numbers from node
        int &getOcc();
        void setLeft(Node *l);          //sets left child pointer
        Node* &getLeft();                //returns left child pointer
        void setRight(Node *r);         //sets right child pointer
        Node* &getRight();               //return right child pointer
};
```

my BST.hpp

```
class BST{

    private:
        Node * root;        //root node pointer

    public:
        BST();                                  //constructor
        ~BST();                                 //destructor
        void Insert(string num, int data);      //Inserts new number in tree
        void InsertIDF(string num, int data);      //Inserts new number in tree
        bool find(string num);                 //finds whether a number is present in tree
        void min();                             //find and print minimum number in the tree
        void max();                             //find and print maximum number in the tree
        void save_file(string filename);        //save the tree to file
        void Delete(string num);                //deletes a number from tree
        void LoadFromFile(string filename);     //loads numbers from file to tree
        void Print();                           //print tree to stdout


        //private functions used as helper functions in the public operations
    private:
        void printHelper(Node *root);
        bool findHelper(Node *root,string num);
        void InsertHelper(Node * &current, string num, int data);
        void InsertHelperIDF(Node * &current, string num, int data);
        void findMinHelper(Node* current);
        void findMaxHelper(Node * current);
        void saveHelper(ofstream &fout, Node* current);
        Node* DeleteHelper(Node *current, string num);
        Node * findMaximum(Node * n);
        void clear(Node *currnt);
};
```

Comment: By recursion, change a value of the current node, and then call the change for the sibling nodes

Comment: You mean, I create a function the change the values and call it in it ?

Comment: You want to add log(2)_base10 to each node in your tree? If I have the value from a single node, in what way do I modify it to give you the result you want?

Comment: I'll edit my post one sec

Comment: Why do you store a number in a string? Well, you may add a method, which takes a pointer to the node as the input, increases the value stored by this $\log_2$ and then calls this method from the silbling nodes. Call this method for the root node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have distinct concepts of a `Node` and a `BST` (which is good), you need one function that acts on a node, modifies the value of the node with whatever rules you decide, and calls itself on that node's children.

Then you can encapsulate this in your BST by having a wrapper function that calls the above function with the root node as the argument.

Get the first one working, then do the next one.

Implementation omitted for a few weeks since this is obviously homework.